# what is the best way to make a forecast in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, forecasting, forecast

I have a data frame like this:

```
|  code  | Week| Amount 
| 20-G   | 1   |33000
| 20-G   | 2   |34000
| 20-G   | 3   |32000
| 20-G   | 4   |70000
| 20-G   | 5   |28000
| 20-G   | 6   |26000
| 20-G   | 7   |50000
| 23-G   | 1   |15000
| 23-G   | 2   |14000
| 23-G   | 3   |12000
| 23-G   | 4   |4000
| 23-G   | 5   |1000
| 28-H   | 1   |60000
| 28-H   | 2   |58000
| 28-H   | 3   |70000
| 28-H   | 4   |30000
```

Each code represents a proyect with specific expenditure amount per week, and each code has a different lead time in weeks.

I am seeking a method to predict the future expenditure for each code over the next few weeks using Python. What would be the most effective approach to perform this forecast?

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this problem as a univariate time series modelling. From you description, I understood that you want to predict the expenditure for each proyect by separate:

1. Split the DataFrame by code. Let's take the 20-G as example:

   ```
   df = df[df["code"] == "20-G"]
   ```
2. Let's make sure the DataFrame is sorted:

   ```
   df.sort_values(by="Week", ascending=True, inplace=True)
   ```
3. Fit your model. Let's use ARIMA, you can install it executing `pip install statsmodels`.

   ```
   from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

   model = ARIMA(df['Amount'], order=(5,1,0))
   model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
   ```
4. Finally, you can try predicting the expenditure amount for the next five weeks:

   ```
   predictions = model_fit.predict(start=len(df), end=len(df)+5)
   ```

Please note that this is a extremely simple approach. Also, `order=(5,1,0)` means that we are considering the 5 previous time periods of our time series (p=5), differencing the time series once to make it stationary (d=1), and not using error values of the past for predictions (q=0).